# Should we have multiple @EnableJpaAuditing annotation in a spring-boot application?

Tags: spring-boot

Spring allows me to add multiple `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotations on different configuration files in an application. But is it recommended? Shall we add this multiple times?

Comment: Why would you need multiple `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotations?

Comment: Its existing on 3 different configuration files in the application. Was wondering, if this should be removed and kept at only once place.